# WorkFlow activity input InArgument as checkbox

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

How can I display all marketing lists with Check boxes? I mean, with this code,

```js
[Input("Team Name")]
[ReferenceTarget("team")]
public InArgument<EntityReference> TeamName { get; set; }
```

I can have a lookup input for team.

I'd like to have all marketing lists as check boxes and assign a contact to one or more marketing lists

Is this possible?

Comment: In a custom workflow activity?

Comment: Yes! Do you know if is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

By default i don't see any way to do this, but you can use Web Resources, do a [html](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536.aspx) or [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328358.aspx) application for do that. With that you can make your layout without restrictions.

Comment: How do you place a web resource within the workflow designer?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot dynamically build the arguments of a custom workflow activity. They have to be defined at compile time.

If you want the user to pick from a number of marketing lists I would just add lots of lookups to marketing lists, then the user can populate them as required.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve if you create a web resource and implement it to do exactly what you want to do. The downside is that it's quite a lot of work. Perhaps you can approach the task from a different angle?

Comment: Do you have any solution type?  I'm new on it!

Comment: How do you place a web resource within the workflow designer?

Comment: @user1200566 The web resource I'm referring to is e.g. an HTML file or JS file that you upload under *Settings -> Solutions -> Web Resources*. I'm not sure what you mean by placing it under a workflow designer. Please elaborate.